# How does one find a basis and dimension for $W^{\perp}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If we're given that W is a 2x2 matrix, with entries $[0, 0, a, 2b]$, how does one find the basis and dimension of $W^{\perp}$?

Comment: Which inner product(/bilinear form) is your space of $2\times 2$ matrices equipped with?  Perhaps the [Frobenius product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product)?

Comment: Actually, I think it is the Euclidean inner product.

Comment: How do you define the Euclidean inner product for square matrices?

Comment: I'm betting you're supposed to use the Frobenius product.  Then you just need to think about what vectors $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)^T$ solve this equation $$v^Tw = \pmatrix{v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & v_4}\pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ a \\ 2b} = \pmatrix{0}$$ for **all** choices of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I still quite don't understand.

Comment: Is it clear to you that $\dim(W) + \dim(W^\perp) = \dim(M_{2\times 2}) = 4$?

Comment: a(0, 0, 1, 0) + b(0, 0, 0, 1), so (0, 0, 1, 0) and (0, 0, 0, 1) are bases of W and thus the dim(W)= 2? And it follows that the orthogonal component would also have dimension of 2?

Comment: If $W$ is a matrix, what's $W^\perp$? You probably want to say that $W$ is the column space of the given matrix. Otherwise, please explain.

Comment: @egreg I actually took $[0, 0, a, 2b]$ to be the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) of an arbitrary matrix in $W$.  It couldn't be the column space if $W$ is a space of $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: @Bye_World I saw your answer, but the question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Frobenius product of a matrix $A = \pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}}\in M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb R)$ and a matrix $B = \pmatrix{b_{11} & b_{12} \\ b_{21} & b_{22}}\in M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb R)$ is given by $A: B = \pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{21} & a_{12} & a_{22}}\pmatrix{b_{11} \\ b_{21} \\ b_{12} \\ b_{22}} = a_{11}b_{11} + a_{21}b_{21} + a_{12}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22}$

If we're trying to find the orthogonal complement of the subspace $U = \operatorname{span}\pmatrix{0 & a \\ 0 & 2b}$ wrt the Frobenius product, then we're just trying to find the space of $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ such that $A: B=0$ for all $B\in W$.  This space is denoted $W^\perp$.

Using the definition of the Frobenius product we see that any matrix $C = \pmatrix{c_{11} & c_{12} \\ c_{21} & c_{22}}$ such that $0c_{11} + 0c_{21} + ac_{12} + 2bc_{22} = ac_{12} + 2bc_{22} = 0$ for all $a,b$ will be in $W^\perp$.  The equation $ac_{12} + 2bc_{22} = 0$ is clearly only solvable for **all** $a,b$ when $c_{12}=c_{22}=0$.  But we have no restrictions on $c_{11}$ or $c_{21}$.  Thus $$W^\perp = \operatorname{span}\pmatrix{c_{11} & 0 \\ c_{21} & 0}$$

Just as a little check we can confirm that $\dim(W) + \dim(W^\perp) = \dim(M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb R))$ is satisfied.  We know that $\dim(M_{2\times 2}) = 4$ and it's very easy to check (I suggest you do so) that $\dim(W) = \dim(W^\perp) = 2$, thus we are correct.

Now can you find a basis for $W^\perp$?

Comment: I believe I made a mistake in the notation, I meant to have a and 2b as the bottom two entries of the matrix.

I managed to get 
a(0, 0, -1/2, 0) + b(0, 0, 0, -2)
so the basis is (0, 0, -1/2, 0) and (0, 0, 0, -2) ?

Comment: Then can you see pretty quickly how to change the form of $W^\perp$ I gave to give you the right answer?  If you mean $\pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ -1/2 & 0}$ and $\pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 0 & -2}$ then that is a basis for $W$ -- not $W^\perp$.

Comment: Then I'm thoroughly lost. I don't mean to be so difficult.

Comment: If $\pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ a & 2b} \to (0,0,a,2b)$ instead of the usual [vectorization of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) then $W^\perp = \operatorname{span}\pmatrix{c & d \\ 0 & 0}$ for $c,d \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$. A basis of $W$ is $\left\{\pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ -1/2 & 0}, \pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 0 & -2}\right\}$ and a basis for $W^\perp$ is $\left\{\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}, \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}\right\}$. Thus $M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb R) = W \oplus W^\perp$ ($M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb R)$ is the [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) of $W$ and $W^\perp$).

Comment: This makes sense and I'm a little embarrassed it took me so long to understand. Thank you for your help and your patience!